# If a computer is able to access a phone via just a USB, what's stopping the phone from accessing the computers filesystem?

Tags: linux, usb, ftp

Okay, lets set away a few limitations, **specifically by the operating system**.

Assume both devices are running a Linux-based Operating System, and that both devices are admin/root.
[CLARIFICATION :  I don't mean the phone is tweaked to run a Linux-Based OS, I mean it runs Linux by default]

How can the Phone be accessed by the computer and not vice versa?
This isn't a **problem**, I'm just curious as to why this happens.

My Theories:

1. The phone has specific drivers that make it a storage device, whereas the computer doesn't
2. The phone has software to make parts of the storage available to read/write operations from a computer

That's about all I have, I tried researching about this subject but couldn't get any results.

Note: I'm not asking for a solution to **how** to get file transfer working, I'm asking **why** would it not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With USB-C charging being the norm now on phones and laptops the USB-C port can appear as host or peripheral, that is because USB-PD/USB-BC charging requires peripheral mode to work.

When plugging a phone or laptop into a USB-A charger the USB-C end of the cable is wired to tell the device to go into "B mode" or peripheral mode.  Depending on the charger and device to be charged they will do a little handshaking to determine how much power can be safely drawn from the charger.  I won't go into this process as that's not the subject under discussion.  The point is that if a laptop or phone can charge using a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable then it supports going into peripheral mode.

If a phone and laptop is connected by a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable, with the USB-C end at the phone, then the phone will appear as a peripheral to the laptop.  That means power can only flow from the laptop to the phone.  Because the phone is the peripheral and the laptop the host the phone is the passive partner, or slave device, on this connection, and the laptop is the active partner or master.  This means the laptop is "driving the bus", in perhaps more figurative ways that literal.  The laptop can ask the phone for data, such as view files on the phone storage, but the opposite won't work unless there's some software in place for that.

Assuming one has a USB-C/male to USB-A/female adapter on the phone a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable can be flipped and now the phone is the host, with the laptop as the peripheral.  In most cases this will only allow the laptop to draw charging power from the phone, which may or may not be what one intends to do.  This power transfer happens because now the laptop is the slave device and the phone is the master.

There are ways to make a laptop do more than just take power as a slave device.  One example is Apple's Target Disk Mode function.  This is software that is stored on the motherboard, outside of the normal operating system.  This makes the laptop act like a "dumb" drive case for the drives inside.  This is useful mostly as a diagnostic tool, a means to recover data from an computer that will not boot and/or repair the files on the drive so it can boot again.

There is software out on the web that allows a Linux computer with USB-C ports to emulate USB peripherals in software.  One of these features is to emulate a storage drive so a connected USB host can read and write files.  One such project for this is called something like "Linux USB Gadgets", with "gadgets" being in reference to the emulated peripherals.  The software allows emulating more than one "gadget" at a time, such as Ethernet, drive storage, and HID (human interface device, like a keyboard, mouse, or joystick).  I will look once in a while on how well this project is going on common laptops, and it appears to be moving slowly.  The point is that it is more than just theoretically possible to make your laptop look like USB peripherals, people have done this.

I mention using a USB-C/male to USB-A/male cable at first only to more easily visualize what is happening since this cable forces which end is the master and slave on the connection, there is no guessing which is which.  This same functionality can be had with a USB-C/male to USB-**C**/male cable.  When a phone and laptop are connected this way there may be slave and master mode roles assigned randomly, or one device or both will make preferences known for the other to follow.  If neither have a preference then roles are determined randomly, if both have the same preference then roles are determined randomly.  If the assigned roles are not to the user's preference then unplugging the cable and reconnecting will trigger a role swap assuming both devices support both roles.

There is a memory on the role swap that could act a bit differently across different platforms.  Unplugging for too short of a time and the devices will not detect the disconnection and reconnection.  Wait too long and the previously assigned roles will be forgotten and the roles might not swap upon reconnect.

As far as I know all computers will a USB-C port will support both host or master role as well as the peripheral or slave mode.  This will certain for laptops that charge by USB-C, and for Apple computers with USB-C.  I suspect all desktop computers with USB-C support going into a peripheral or slave mode too, I just haven't tried this myself yet or seen someone demonstrate this working.

In the USB spec since USB 3.0 is a peer-to-peer mode.  This is a rarely used mode, and when used appears to be exclusively used as a software development tool, a means to get data out of a computer when other ports are not available for debug data.  Ethernet and serial ports appear to be preferable.  Peer-to-peer by USB 3.x where both computers have USB-A ports will require use of what's often called a "debugging cable".  I suspect that peer-to-peer communication by USB when one or both computers have USB-C ports will not require a special cable, just one capable of "superspeed" data transfer speeds.

Smart phones will have the software to act as master or slave from their USB-C port, which describes the experience you've had.  Getting similar software on a personal computer is possible, it's just quite complicated yet.

How this works is with the right software installed onto a Linux computer.  There may also be a requirement for a specific kind of USB-C controller, I just haven't seen reference to this yet.  Perhaps there's been no mention for this as every computer has dual-role USB-C ports.

Answer (score 1):

The computer has USB hardware and software that can only be a host for other devices and so it cannot be a device to another host. Some mobile phones can support being a host and you can connect these to other devices like USB mass media or MIDI keyboards, but it requires a special cable so that the phone understands that it has an adapter so it should switch roles to be the host.